# Windows 7 restart keeps freezing?

Tags: windows-7, reboot

A few days ago I restarted my computer, which I usually have zero problems with. However, this time it stopped in the middle of a restart at one screen. I tried again multiple times and it just stayed in the same place.

It gets stuck on a black screen. There is a command-prompt cursor at the top left that flashes, but it just stays like that, typing won't change anything.

I've tried to get to the advanced startup screen using <kbd>F8</kbd> like many other sources say you should, but it won't show up. This computer has had no recent issues either, so I'm pretty much clueless on what to try next.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has onboard diagnostics, run them. If a hard drive is starting to fail, but hasn't failed completely, then a OS will sometimes get corrupted and even getting into Safe Mode is a problem.

Comment: Your answer is like a comment

Answer (score 0):

Since your computer does not beep, the Power On Self Test (POST) has been successful. But the **Windows bootloader has been corrupted/deleted** for some reason. Boot from the Windows Recovery CD and click on **Automatic Repair**. The problem should be solved.

If you don't have the Recovery CD, just download the disk image from the internet and make a bootable USB (using, I recommend, *Rufus*).